# Not working IDENTITY_INSERT in SQL Server Compact with Entity Framework 6.4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, identity, ef-database-first

I want to add a record with a specific `ID` into the database, but when I write and run this code, the line created starts with the number one. My `ID` is identity and I disable identity insert with the following code:

```
Db = new Entitites();

Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT CarName ON");

Db.CarName.Add(new MrSanadBaseDb.CarName()
   {
        PK_Car = 120,
        Name = "",
        IsDeleted = false
   });

Db.SaveChanges();
Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT CarName OFF;");
Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"ALTER TABLE CarName ALTER COLUMN PK_Car IDENTITY (121,1);");
```

But the record is not saved with `ID = 120`, the record is saved with `ID = 1`.

I work with SQL Server Compact Edition (SQL Server CE).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity insert is session (connection-open) scoped. Did you create the db-context with an **already open** connection? Or did you give it a connection string, or a closed connection? If it is opening the connection per operation: there is no session continuity, so each if the three operations is semantically unrelated, and do not share a session.

Based on that default constructor, I think it is using the "lookup default connection string, use deferred connection" approach. Try using the constructor that takes a connection instead, and **make sure it is open first**.

Specifically:

```cs
using var conn = // ... create connection
conn.Open();
Db = new Entitites(conn);
// ... the rest of your code
```

Comment: @mohammad I should also note: if EF thinks that the PK is an identity column, EF may not want to do this insert for you, as it **won't supply** the PK-ID for an insert. As such, you might need to do this insert via your own SQL

Comment: is my connection string 
**metadata=res://*/MrSanadBase.csdl|res://*/MrSanadBase.ssdl|res://*/MrSanadBase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string='Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db.sdf;Max Database Size=4091;Password=*****'**

Comment: @Mohammad then frankly, I think you're going to have to forget EF for this bit and just use SQL